# python - selenium - firefox driver options settings

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Python - I worked with selenium chrome driver, but headless mode did not work properly.

After checking, I heard that headless mode works normally when working with the Firefox driver.

But since the site I'm working on detects selenium, I need to work with the settings below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) '
                                                                     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                                                                     'Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36'})
```

After switching to the firefox driver, I tried various settings with the information obtained through the search, but it did not work. Is it possible to set up a firefox driver that can achieve the same effect as the chrome driver setting above? please tell me how

Comment: What is the url you are trying to access, is it publicly accesible?

Comment: I want to make it public, but it's meaningless because it's a place you have to log in to see.